# UITableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle never called in swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing, swift3, xcode8

[image]

As I am new in Swift I got stuck in a situation. I am working on a app in which I want show side index section like in a contact app. I have used this code in my app

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int{
     print(sections.index(of:title)!)
     return sections.index(of:title)!
 }
```

But this method never get called, And the TableView is not showing the side index section. I am using Swift 3. Any help will be appreciated.

I have a tableview in which country list is there now i want to focus particular section with selection of section index (A..Z). I have implemented the above code but section index is not showing.

Comment: I might suggest starting with the Master-Detail template. This functionality you are looking for comes default.

Comment: ok let me try and thanks

Comment: Let me know if it works. If it does I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Not working in  Master-Detail template too

Comment: Is this for iPhone or iPad?

Comment: am testing on iPhone

Comment: If I am correct you don't have a split view on an iPhone, You don't have enough space. You have a split view on the iPad as it is larger. Am I correct?

Comment: Now i have tested it on iPad also. again its section index not showing.

Comment: Using the master detail template? It should work. It looks like there might be a bug that can happen on occasion. I found [this article](https://www.imobie.com/support/how-to-fix-split-screen-not-working-on-ipad.htm) that might help.

Comment: Have you implemented sectionIndexTitlesForTableView  ?

Comment: Hey Yogendra i have  func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]!{
        return self.sections
    }

Comment: but do i need to call this method from viewdidload?

Comment: Have you connected UITavleview delegate, datasource ?

Comment: @KrishnaKumar post more details for your code

Answer (score 2):

After a long research got the solution i was doing a silly mistake. To focus on selected section we need to scroll the tableView at selected section with this code.

You can see complete code here :https://github.com/ipraba/EPContactsPicker/blob/master/Pods/EPContactsPicker.swift

```
override open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
          //  if resultSearchController.isActive { return 0 }
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: index), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top , animated: false)
            return sections.index(of: title)!
        }
```